# How to attach eye armature to rigify armature?

Tags: rigging, armature, rigify

Im creating a character, and Im using a rigify armature for the body. and a normal armature for the eyes, I used a Keep offset setting to parent the eye´s armature to the rigify armature, but when I move the head bone the eyes blows up!

[image]

Comment: Hi David you mind posting a .blend?  You can use pasteall.org/blend for a quick place to upload.

Comment: Parent your eye bones to the "ORG-head" bone instead of the "head" bone

Answer (score 0):

Rigify armature is really confusing with all those names so what I always do to parent head with new bones for the eyes is to select head bone in edit mode, add a new bone and then add other bone that is going to move one eye and then do the same for the other eye.

After that select the bone that is in the middle connecting eyes with head and delete it. You will have eyes parented with the correct bone head.

I know there are probably other way to do that